# Black Fragment when loaded the first time in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, surfaceview

I have a FragmentActivity which loads 3 fragments in a view pager. At each fresh install, the second fragment is loaded but soon after it turns black. After this, the second fragment is reloaded and works ok even while swiping through the views. So, it turns black only the first time it's loaded. I implemented this using a FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter but it behaves the same. This happens only for KitKat and Lollipop. All of the fragments have simple layouts, no nested fragments.

```
    public class IntroActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        private List<Fragment> listFragments;
        private PagerAdapter pagerAdapterWelcome;
        private OnboardingPager viewPager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.intro_pager);
            viewPager = (OnboardingPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            //Initializing the List
            listFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
            //initializing the fragments
            WelcomeFragment welcomeFragment = new WelcomeFragment();
            TicketScanFragment ticketOptionScanFragment = new TicketScanFragment();
            ScannerFragment scanFragment = new ScannerFragment();

            //Adding Fragments to List
            listFragments.add(welcomeFragment);
            listFragments.add(ticketOptionScanFragment);
            listFragments.add(scanFragment);

            //initializing PagerAdapter
            pagerAdapterWelcome = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), listFragments);
            viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapterWelcome);

            final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabDots);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true);
    }
```

Adapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

            private List<Fragment> listFragments;


            public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> listFragments) {
                super(fm);
                this.listFragments = listFragments;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i) {
                return listFragments.get(i);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return listFragments.size();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the third fragment which instantiated a SurfaceView. It seems that ViewPager by default destroys and creates views that are out of the screen. So in order to block this I added in my FragmentActivity

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(listFragments.size());
```

With this is specified the number of undestroyable views. Before adding this the number of children the ViewPager has was always smaller with one page and now I understand why, the SurfaceView was always destroyed because it out of the screen. Finally, no more black screen/flicker.

Comment: This only works if you are not trying to do setCurrentItem. I am trying to use this and also have position 1 be shown on startup.

Comment: you saved my life

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help your situation: you can try to make the following change to the way you instantiate the view pager adapter:

```
//initializing PagerAdapter
pagerAdapterWelcome = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), listFragments);
```

here a documentation link: [documentation nested fragments](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

Comment: Thank you, but the fragments are added to a FragmentActivity and not to another Fragment. There are no nested fragments.

Comment: Did you try to Override the getItemPosition() method inside the PagerAdapter and make it return POSITION_NONE ? (just to see what happen). Also in this case, call pagerAdapterWelcome.notifyDataSetChanged() inside the onCreate method of IntroActivity

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I overrided getItemPosition() to return POSITION_NONE and also called pagerAdapterWelcome.notifyDataSetChanged() and still behaves the same. I did more tests and on Lollipop the second screen flickers, the black screen time is shorter. However this doesn't happen at all on Marshmallow.

Comment: One more thing, the third fragment is a CameraSourcePreview. If I remove this fragment there's no more flicker/black screen.